# How do I change the color of the frame in ColorBox?

Tags: colors, frame, colorbox

I am new to jQuery and although I have got 90% of what I want to do sorted out I am not able to change the colour of the frame in ColorBox from gray. I have been through the code and have read through the settings section of http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox but cannot see where it is set. Help would be much appeciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no javascript option for you to change the color. You will have to do it via CSS. It will vary depending on which "theme" you are using, and you may have to edit or create new images for it.